# How to kill other applications from a system application in Android

Tags: android, linux

I have rooted my mobile and I have made my application as system application by granting the required permissions. Now, I have tried using:

```
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

by giving the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

My application is still not able to close other applications. I have tried closing what's app from my application. The above code is getting executed without any errors. Though my application is a system application( I have tried my application as user application too), but still linux kernel is ignoring the call to kill other applications.

I know it is not good to kill other applications from our own applications, but I want to know what else should I need to do to kill other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, 
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid); 
allows the system to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app;

You can try killing third party apps via command line:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.my.app.package
```

And of course you can run this command from java also.

Comment: I have used the below code to run that command in java:
public void RunAsRoot(String cmd){
    Process p;
   try {
 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(cmd);
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        os.flush();
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   Log.d("command not run", e.getMessage());
   Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong while killing the application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
It has got executed, but still the code for displaying currently running applicatio shows the same list.

Comment: No exception got raised saying you have no permissions to kill other applications.